# Kähler-Einstein metric on blowup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology, kahler-manifolds

Given a nonsingular variety $X$ of dimension $n \geq 3$ with a Kähler-Einstein metric and a smooth curve $C \subset X$ of genus $g \geq 2$. Denote the blowup $Y = Bl_C X$. Then $Y$ is Kähler. If we assume that $Y$ is Fano then so is $X$ (Proposition 3.5 in ["On contractions of extremal rays of Fano manifolds"](https://eudml.org/doc/153328)).

- If $Y$ has a Kähler-Einstein metric does it imply that $X$ admits a Kähler-Einstein metric as well?

Equivalently,

- If the blowup of a nonsingular manifold at a genus $g \geq 2$ smooth curve is K-polystable, does it mean the original manifold is?

Comment: You must be missing a hypothesis.  The class of Fano manifolds is bounded.  However, since there are infinitely many genera $g\geq 2$ and infinitely many curve classes that support curves of genus $g$, the class of blowups of $X$ is not a bounded family.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed accordingly.

Comment: This is good question, See Theorem 2, which is inverse of your question https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0760.pdf